# Show that all the zeros of $g$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider the function:

$$g(α,β)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}((n^{2α-1}-1)/n^{α}) n^{iβ}$$

My **question** is: Show that **all the zeros** of $g$ in $0<α<1$ have the form $(1/2,β)$ where $β$ is real.

Comment: Is this not equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis?

Comment: @robjohn: No, this assertion would imply the Riemann hypothesis. See http://vixra.org/author/zeraoulia_elhadj.

Comment: Not to be too harsh about it, but... do you have any reason to believe that this phrasing of the question will bring some insight to the problem that a hundred years of concerted mathematical effort have not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As robjohn suggests in his comment, this assertion would imply the Riemann hypothesis and proving it would win you a million dollars.

To be precise, your equation is equivalent to $$\eta(s)=\eta(1-\bar s),$$ where $s=\alpha-i\beta$ and $$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$$ denotes the *Dirichlet Eta function*.

If the Riemann hypothesis were false, there would be an $s$ with $0<\Re{ s}<1$, $\Re s\neq 1/2$ such that $\zeta(s)=0$ and (by the functional equation of the zeta function) $\zeta(1-\bar s)=\overline{\zeta(1-s)}=0$, hence you would obtain a solution to $\eta(s)=0=\eta(1-\bar s)$ with $\alpha\neq 1/2$.